# What does the word "extend" mean in the context of model theory?

Tags: terminology, first-order-logic, model-theory, filters

Consider the following two problems:

(1) Let $L=\{E\}$ be a language consisting one binary relation symbol. Let $T$ be the $L$-theory saying that $E$ is an equivalence relation with infinitely many classes. Prove that there are infinitely many inequivalent complete theories **extendin**g $T$.

(2) Prove that an ultrafilter on an infinite set is non-principal if  and only if it **extends** to the Frechet filter.

In both problems, I don't understand what the word "extend" means.

Can someone explain to me? Thanks!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I understand what it means to extend a structure or a language. But what does it mean by extending a theory?  And what does it mean by extending an filter to the frechet filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Extend" just means "be a superset of" in this context.  So a theory $T'$ extends a theory $T$ if $T\subseteq T'$, and a filter $F'$ extends a filter $F$ if $F\subseteq F'$.

(The phrasing "extends *to*" in statement (2) is an error and should be just "extends".  Indeed, saying "$F$ extends to $F'$" would normally mean that $F'$ extends $F$, which is the opposite of the intended meaning here: it means to say that the ultrafilter extends the Frechet filter.)